# Perl 6 - Curried Function Hangs

Tags: functional-programming, currying, raku

So, I wanted to be able to write a function that will figure out all the ways that you could make change for a specific amount of money, using coins of different values.

So, I wrote a function `coin` that tells you for a given amount, how many ways you can make change for that value, given a certain value coin, and a function that will calculate how many ways you could make change, with the same kinds of parameters for the next smaller coin.

I then tried to write a function `ladder` that I want to return a function that for an @array of coin values will return a function takes a single formal parameter `$amt` that calculates the number of ways that you could make change for that amount given the values of the coins specified in the array.

I tried to use the `&coin` function with an `.assuming` method to add in the values of coins and build up the appropriate ladder. Unfortunately, it hangs when I try to run the resulting function.

```
my @values = 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200;
#the coin of value 1 is assumed as a base case

my &test = ladder(@values);

say &test(5);

sub ladder(@values) {
        my &base = sub () { return @values.shift };
        for @values {
                &base = &coin.assuming(*,$_,&base);
        }
        return &base;
}

sub coin($amt,$value,&lesser) {
        if $amt >= $value {
                return &coin($amt-$value,$value,&lesser) + &lesser($amt);
        } else {
                return &lesser($amt);
        }
}
```

To give an idea it &ladders should produce the equivalent of &twopd in the below series of functions.

```
sub twopd($amt) { return &coin($amt,200,&onepd) };

sub onepd($amt) { return &coin($amt,100,&fifp) };

sub fifp($amt) { return &coin($amt,50,&twep) };

sub twep($amt) { return &coin($amt,20,&tenp) };

sub tenp($amt) { return &coin($amt,10,&fivp) };

sub fivp($amt) { return &coin($amt,5,&twop) };

sub twop($amt) { return &coin($amt,2,&onep) };

sub onep($amt) { return 1 };
```

I was wondering if anyone might have an idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- `sub () { return @values.shift }` will remove a value from `@values` everytime it gets called, which is not what you want.
- `&coin.assuming(*,$_,&base)` needs to do something with the `&base` so that it gets the current value in `&base` and not what is left in it at the end of the loop. One option is to add `|` in front of it and another is to use `<>` to decontainerize the value.

It is probably a good idea to add some caching to `coin` as it will get called with the same arguments many times for larger values.

```perl6
sub ladder ( +@ ($initial, *@values) ) {
    my &base = -> $ { $initial };
    for @values {
        &base = &coin.assuming: *,  $_, &base<>;
    }
    return &base;
}

use experimental :cached;

sub coin ( $amt, $value, &lesser ) is cached {
    if $amt >= $value {
        coin( $amt - $value, $value, &lesser ) + lesser($amt);
    } else {
        lesser( $amt );
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow it works! Thank you so much! I'll have to look up with the | does in front of &base.

Comment: @user6189164 [`&prefix:«|»`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#prefix_%7C) puts its argument into a Slip. I think it is just causing the `&base` to refer to the current value of `&base` and not the value that is left in `&base` at the very end of the loop.

Comment: Thank you! I also noticed that you write "-> $ { $initial }"; I noticed that if I leave out the "$", it doesn't work properly (I get the "Too many positionals passed; expected 0 arguments but got 1" error). I tried to find the " $ " in the documentation but couldn't find it. Is the " $ " just saying that the lambda that takes no parameters?

Comment: @user6189164 The `$` is there to say it takes one value, but it doesn't need a name because it isn't used.

Comment: @user6189164 The best doc for your interest would have been [The `$` Variable](https://docs.perl6.org/language/variables#The_$_Variable). I've opened doc issue [#1861](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/1861).